# Move a ball ( an ellipse) at a certain speed to where the mouse was clicked - Processing 3

Tags: processing

I am trying to move a ball(an ellipse) to the position of where the mouse was recently clicked but i don't want it to jump there I want it to move at a certain speed there.
This is my code

```
int BallX = 200;
int BallY = 150;
final int BALL_SIZE = 30; // size of the ball
final int SPEED = 10; // the ball should move at this speed
void setup(){
 size(500 , 500); //canvas size
}
 void draw(){
  drawBall();
 }
void drawBall(){
fill(255);
ellipse(BallX , BallY ,BALL_SIZE,BALL_SIZE); // the ball
}
void mouseClicked(){
golfBallX = pmouseX;
golfBallY = pmouseY;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a smooth movement I recommend to the calculation with floating point values (`double`):

You have to declare variables for the position of the ball and the target position where the ball should go to. At the initial state, both positions have to be the same:

```
double  BallX = 200.0;
double  BallY = 150.0;
double  targetBallX = 200.0;
double  targetBallY = 150.0;
```

Calculate the distance between the current position oft the ball and the target position, in the `draw function`:

```
double deltaX = targetBallX - BallX;
double deltaY = targetBallY - BallY;
double dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY);
```

If the current position is different from the target position, then do a step in the direction of the target:

```
if ( dist > 0.0 ) {
    double step = Math.min(dist, SPEED);
    BallX += step * deltaX / dist;
    BallY += step * deltaY / dist;
}
```

The full code may look like this:

```
double  BallX = 200.0;
double  BallY = 150.0;
double  targetBallX = 200.0;
double  targetBallY = 150.0;

final int    BALL_SIZE = 30; // size of the ball
final double SPEED = 10.0; // the ball should move at this speed

void setup(){
   size(500 , 500); //canvas size
}

void draw(){

    double deltaX = targetBallX - BallX;
    double deltaY = targetBallY - BallY;
    double dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY);
    if ( dist > 0.0 ) {
        double step = Math.min(dist, SPEED);
        BallX += step * deltaX / dist;
        BallY += step * deltaY / dist;
    }

    drawBall();
}

void drawBall(){ 
    background(128);
    fill(255);
    ellipse((int)BallX, (int)BallY, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE); // the ball
}

void mouseClicked(){
    targetBallX = (double)pmouseX;
    targetBallY = (double)pmouseY;
}
```